# Mocha ingores tests, how to launch the all

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, elasticsearch, mocha.js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am creating a node.js plugin to post data to elasticsearch. I have four unit tests in my test file. However mocha launches only the two of them and ignores the others. What should I do to launch them all, how such behavior can be explained?
Here are my tests:

```
describe('Module', () => {

let DataLogger = require('../dist/index.js').DataLogger;

it('should exist', ()=>{
    expect(new DataLogger()).to.exist;
});

describe('checkCon index name is missed', () => {
    DataLogger.checkCon(null, indexDocParams, 'add', (error, success) => {
        it('success should return null', () => {
            expect(success).to.equal(null);
        });
    });
});

describe('checkCon index does not exist', () =>{
    DataLogger.checkCon('a', indexDocParams, 'add', (error, success)=>{
        it('success should return null', () => {
            expect(success).to.equal(null);
        });
    });
});

describe('checkCon doc added', () =>{
    DataLogger.checkCon('structnew', indexDocBody, 'add', (error, success)=>{
        it('error should return null', () => {
            expect(error).to.equal(null);
        });
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put your it statements inside the callbacks of code uber test. Mocha builds it's test list at load time, so it statements like that may not get picked up.

Try rewriting as:

```
describe('checkCon doc added', () =>{
  it('error should return null', (done) => {
    DataLogger.checkCon('structnew', indexDocBody, 'add', (error, success)=>{
        if(error) { 
          return done(error);
        }

        expect(error).to.equal(null);
        done()
    });
});
```

});

**EDIT** added return statement on error to ensure done is not called twice

Comment: You should `return` if there is an `error`. Otherwise you're calling `done` twice which results in a Mocha "done called multiple times" exception.

Comment: Oops, indeed. Typo on my behalf while writing answers via mobile on the bus. I'll update